MongoDB aggregate: $match should return documents for an unique property
I have a collection, where I would like to write a query to have records based on a condition that should return records for unique itemId, but still I don't know the value of itemId. Here are some dummy documents:
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("669bdcf703fbdb780ed31832"),
    widgetType: "custom-form",
    label: "Product",
    itemId: ObjectId("669bdcf603fbdb780ed31830"),
    formId: ObjectId("669bdbd203fbdb780ed314cb"),
    slug: "product",
    value: "648d6d0f221f77c425aac3b9",
    disabled: "false",
    trashed: "false",
    widgetId: ObjectId("669bdbd203fbdb780ed314cd")
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("669bdd0203fbdb780ed3183e"),
    widgetType: "custom-form",
    label: "Product",
    itemId: ObjectId("669bdd0203fbdb780ed3183c"),
    formId: ObjectId("669bdbd203fbdb780ed314cb"),
    slug: "product",
    value: "648d6d0f221f77c425aac3b9",
    disabled: "false",
    trashed: "false",
    widgetId: ObjectId("669bdbd203fbdb780ed314cd")
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("669bdd0203fbdb780ed31841"),
    widgetType: "select",
    label: "Status",
    itemId: ObjectId("669bdd0203fbdb780ed3183c"),
    formId: ObjectId("669bdbd203fbdb780ed314cb"),
    slug: "status",
    value: "approved",
    disabled: "false",
    trashed: "false",
    widgetId: ObjectId("669bdbd203fbdb780ed314d0")
  }
]

Here is my query, where I would like to have documents that belongs to a single itemId.
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          $and: [
            {
              widgetId: ObjectId("669bdbd203fbdb780ed314cd")
            },
            {
              value: "648d6d0f221f77c425aac3b9"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          $and: [
            {
              widgetId: ObjectId("669bdbd203fbdb780ed314d0")
            },
            {
              value: "approved"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      // Should return two documents for an unique `itemId`

    }
  }
])

According to my requirement, the query should return two documents since both documents are belong to a itemId like following.
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("669bdd0203fbdb780ed3183e"),
    "disabled": "false",
    "formId": ObjectId("669bdbd203fbdb780ed314cb"),
    "itemId": ObjectId("669bdd0203fbdb780ed3183c"),
    "label": "Product",
    "slug": "product",
    "trashed": "false",
    "value": "648d6d0f221f77c425aac3b9",
    "widgetId": ObjectId("669bdbd203fbdb780ed314cd"),
    "widgetType": "custom-form"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("669bdd0203fbdb780ed31841"),
    "disabled": "false",
    "formId": ObjectId("669bdbd203fbdb780ed314cb"),
    "itemId": ObjectId("669bdd0203fbdb780ed3183c"),
    "label": "Status",
    "slug": "status",
    "trashed": "false",
    "value": "approved",
    "widgetId": ObjectId("669bdbd203fbdb780ed314d0"),
    "widgetType": "select"
  }
]

How can I do that?
My current query returns three documents, where one document from another itemId.
https://mongoplayground.net/p/YOsa7vGqCe5

so what happen if your condition match 4 documents. 2 each have the same itemid

so basically you can group by itemId in the end https://mongoplayground.net/p/2EgjggNjA4c

Actually, I don't need to group all of the items by itemId, where it is another use case in practical scenario. I only need documents that belong to an item. @cmgchess

how is it decided to which itemId you want if you dont know item id

I want it should be decided by the two $and conditions, where they should be from same itemId.

first group by itemid and then filter? https://mongoplayground.net/p/_9ofEzQ8P3S

I think, it would not be an efficient approach, because we really don't need all items to group where we only need an item.

you are correct regarding first grouping it is inefficent. maybe i dont understand your question properly. what is your 2 and conditons mean. since there is an or wrapping you will get if at least 1 and condition success. do you want documents with both and conditions have satisified

Sure thing! Two $and conditions are wrapped with a $or condition, so every $and condition would return at least one document, finally for the $or wrapping it would return at least two documents at least (if available).
So my expected result is, when I get two documents (if available) both of them should have same itemId. If you check mongoplayground link it returns three documents, because for first $and condition it returns two documents with different itemId. So, I need a solution where first $and condition will return one document that has same itemId like second one.

@user3384985 from your definition grouping is unavoidable, but I believe you did not fully explained what you are doing. Which _id would you expect in the result from this collection: https://mongoplayground.net/p/K83O51iisOU  (matches 2 products with same itemId, no statuses)?  And this one: https://mongoplayground.net/p/fQeqm_q5IQv (matches all 4, 2 pairs with the same itemId each)?

Here the important property is itemId for the result output. I need two documents return from the query where both have same itemId. My given query does not return my expected result, because it does not check unique itemId. That's why it returns total three documents where one have different itemId than others.

say there is a situation instead of 3 documents you get 4 documents. 2 documents have itemId=1, other 2 also same itemId=2.  then what should be the output

@AlexBlex If I change the itemId it still returns three documents, but I want two documents where both itemId are same. (https://mongoplayground.net/p/mGcAJgPsscA)
For your given playground (https://mongoplayground.net/p/K83O51iisOU) - I want there would be no document in return.

@cmgchess Documents count depends on the $and condition. So, if there are four $and conditions it would return four documents maximum because every item have unique widgetId. That means every document should have same $itemId. For this particular query, we consider only having documents for a single item (itemId).

i meant like this actually https://mongoplayground.net/p/y3xsLC-g_7v . what would the itemId be here

@cmgchess In this case, according to my requirement it would return two documents where both have same itemId - ObjectId("669bdd0203fbdb780ed3183c").
So result output with two documents where _id are 2,3
Your given link - https://mongoplayground.net/p/y3xsLC-g_7v

As I mentioned, currently my query does not give me the expected result. So, I need a solution for that.

@user3384985 for mongoplayground.net/p/y3xsLC-g_7v  how do you decide which 2 out of 4 to return? there are 2 pairs with same itemId: 2, 3 share itemId ending with 83c and 1, 4 share itemId ending with 830

My bad, I didn't see itemId of 1 & 4. Right now, I don't have any duplicate widgetId for a single item. If there is duplicate, I need to add unique value out there like _id instead of widgetId as well. Thank you for pointing out that.
But still, I need to filter out the output based on itemId

@user3384985 "I don't have any duplicate " - this is exactly what I meant by you not sharing enough context of the question. i.e. something that you consider obvious for you  as intrinsic domain knowledge, but totally hidden from us as we see only information you shared in the question.  As a side note, "I don't have any duplicate" might be true today, but it would be quite naive to assume it will hold forever. You should be prepared how to handle duplicates in the code really.

So all in all, don't bother with premature optimisation an efficiency until you prove it is an issue. You have much more problems with handling data and refining requirements. Group as the chess master told, analyse content of the array to guarantee you have exactly 1 product and exactly 1 status in the array, if I get your answers right, etc.  Let me stress it again - don't trust production data would be ideal and always match the example in your spec. use mgeneratejs or mgodatagen to chaos-test your code on random data and handle exceptions gracefully on application level.

@AlexBlex Agreed! I could do that assumption beforehand and it must be done to handle future mess up of the feature. As the feature is now in very basic stage it would be problematic in future where existing code returns multiple records even though I expected the one. Thank you both Alex and cmgchess for pointing out that. I would try to fix it through grouping out the result by itemId but still need to filter where all widgets would present for an item.

after grouping you can $match on the array size
